# Missing methods on urllib

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Why can't use `urllib` on my Python 3.4 installation?

I can import it, but I can't use any method:

```
Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import urllib
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

EDIT:

I can't see sub modules either:

```
>>> dir(urllib.request)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    dir(urllib.request)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'
>>>
```

Comment: You have to import `urllib.request` first, then call `dir` on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dir` is misleading you. There are several sub-modules of `urllib` in Python 3.x: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/urllib.html

```
>>> import urllib
>>> dir(urllib)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__']
>>> import urllib.request
>>> dir(urllib.request)
['AbstractBasicAuthHandler', 'AbstractDigestAuthHandler', 'AbstractHTTPHandler', 'BaseHandler', 'CacheFTPHandler', 'ContentTooShortError', 'FTPHandler', 'FancyURLopener', 'FileHandler', 'HTTPBasicAuthHandler', 'HTTPCookieProcessor', 'HTTPDefaultErrorHandler', 'HTTPDigestAuthHandler', 'HTTPError', 'HTTPErrorProcessor', 'HTTPHandler', 'HTTPPasswordMgr', 'HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm', 'HTTPRedirectHandler', 'HTTPSHandler', 'MAXFTPCACHE', 'OpenerDirector', 'ProxyBasicAuthHandler', 'ProxyDigestAuthHandler', 'ProxyHandler', 'Request', 'URLError', 'URLopener', 'UnknownHandler', '__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__version__', '_cut_port_re', '_ftperrors', '_have_ssl', '_localhost', '_noheaders', '_opener', '_parse_proxy', '_proxy_bypass_macosx_sysconf', '_safe_gethostbyname', '_thishost', '_urlopener', 'addclosehook', 'addinfourl', 'base64', 'bisect', 'build_opener', 'collections', 'email', 'ftpcache', 'ftperrors', 'ftpwrapper', 'getproxies', 'getproxies_environment', 'hashlib', 'http', 'install_opener', 'io', 'localhost', 'noheaders', 'os', 'parse_http_list', 'parse_keqv_list', 'pathname2url', 'posixpath', 'proxy_bypass', 'proxy_bypass_environment', 'quote', 'random', 'randombytes', 're', 'request_host', 'socket', 'splitattr', 'splithost', 'splitpasswd', 'splitport', 'splitquery', 'splittag', 'splittype', 'splituser', 'splitvalue', 'ssl', 'sys', 'thishost', 'time', 'to_bytes', 'unquote', 'unwrap', 'url2pathname', 'urlcleanup', 'urljoin', 'urlopen', 'urlparse', 'urlretrieve', 'urlsplit', 'urlunparse']
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I can't see the sub-modules either.

Comment: @stenci Does importing them actual fail?

Comment: The import gives no error messages. The output on the post is fully copied from idle.

Comment: I didn't notice the second `import`. I was importing only `urllib`, not `urllib.request`.

Comment: Still something weird: why `import os` `os.path.basename()` works, but `import urllib` `urllib.parse.urlencode()` doesn't?

Comment: It has to do with the way the `os` module is defined vs how the `urllib` module is defined. The `os` module is actually defined in `os.py`, and the `path` module is directly imported inside it. However, there is no urllib.py; There's a just urllib directory, which contains `__init__.py` (which is an empty file), `request.py`, `parse.py`, `error.py`, `response.py`, etc. So when you import urllib, it's actually importing the empty urllib/__init__.py file. You have to import `urllib.something` to get actual content.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'm a little disappointed: this is the first inconsistency that I found as I'm learning (and loving) Python :)

Comment: 3 years later I stumbled upon the same issue... thank you for clarification.